# Post or Page specific image gallery in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way from which I can use any plugin and show `Post` or `Page` specific image gallery? The image gallery upload area should be displayed in Page when Creating or Editing the page below or above the text composer or should be at least in the page. And this gallery should not be hocked the default Image gallery of wordpress or at least should not show the images that's in default gallery.

Kindly let me know if anybody knows any plugin that does the above mentioned job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by [gallery] shortcode. You can also set image ids like this: [gallery ids="729,732,731,720"]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I need the gallery area to be displayed in page above or below the text composer while creating new or editing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer: All my requirement got fulfilled by default "Media Library" tab. I just need to select the option "Uploaded to this page" from the dropdown. So, no need to use any plugin for the requirement I had.

[image: Screenshot of Media Library]